# addObject in NSMutableArray error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am trying to show or hide buttons for actions you can take for a contact depending on whether certain data is present, i.e. there is a phone number or facebookid.  The following code compiles but then crashes on the buttonsToHide line.

```
NSMutableArray *buttonsToShow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:self.facebookButton,self.callButton, self.smsButton, self.emailButton, self.deleteButton, nil];   
NSMutableArray *buttonsToHide = [NSMutableArray array];

NSLog(@"Facbook id is:%@",self.contact.facebookID);

if (self.contact.facebookID == nil) {
    [buttonsToShow removeObject:self.facebookButton];
    //Following line crashes and shows up in green
    [buttonsToHide addObject:self.facebookButton];
}
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on what is causing it to crash.

Comment: What happens when the code "crashes"?  What actual error are you getting?

Comment: The app crashes and the method opens in Xcode with a breakpoint so it is highlighted in green.it says buttonsToHide =(NSMutableArray *) @"0 objects"

Comment: What is the actual error you are receiving though?  That is not an error

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but where do I find the actual error? I tried replacing array with arrayWithObjects.  It crashes in exactly same way suggesting problem may be with addObject

Comment: It does say lldb in log.  Is it possible I just put in accidental breakpoint?  I don't see option to delete the breakpoint.

Comment: CMD(⌘)+7 to show all, then CMD(⌘)+A to select all and then delete with backspace.

Comment: I deleted all the breakpoints (there were 8), deleted the app and rebuilt and ran.  Now it crashes in the same spot and gives sigbart error with following:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: @user12345 so you see the reason, your self.facebookButton suppose to be nil.

Comment: facebookButton is a property.  Do I have to alloc init it to make it a proper object?

Comment: I have no clue how it supposed to be initialised, but I can assume that it must be connected to some button on storyboard then it's enough, did you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly isn't crashing on the second array allocation, but on the first, and that crash is almost certainly caused by one the elements in the initialization being nil.

```
NSMutableArray *buttonsToShow;
if (self.facebookButton && self.callButton && self.smsButton && self.emailButton && self.deleteButton) {
    buttonsToShow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:self.facebookButton,self.callButton, self.smsButton, self.emailButton, self.deleteButton, nil];  
} else {
    buttonsToShow = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSLog(@"didn't initialize the array because placing nil objects in an array causes a crash");
}
```

Are those buttons IBOutlets?  Possibly not hooked up?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `self.facebookButton` is nil. Verify if they are initialized if they are code programmatically or connected to the views in the interface builder.

The following code will avoid the crash. But you may want to check why `self.facebookButton` is nil and fix

```
if (self.contact.facebookID == nil && self.facebookButton) {
    [buttonsToShow removeObject:self.facebookButton];
    //Following line crashes and shows up in green
    [buttonsToHide addObject:self.facebookButton];
}
```